# make a label editable with click event in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Lets take the following scenario:

1. The user enter value by several control items, like , textbox, listbox, combobox, radio button.
2. The user press the submit button and all the values entered by the user sent to the server.
3. The admin can view the details submitted by the user, and edit them if required.

Now while editing the user input by admin with click event, is it possible bring back the same type of controls(textbox/combo-box/radiobutton, etc.) when the user used to enter its input for the first time ?

Comment: I didn't get exact but do you mean that when user submit the form admin can edit the same form and revert back to user again if needed

Comment: The admin will edit the same form if required and will not revert back to user. After the necessary changes made by admin, the user input will just proceed further for processing.

Comment: just get the saved details from the server and show the details in the same form.